# jQuery fadeout message after 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my Rails app, after the success of the AJAX action, a flash message appears with the message "Patient Added". Because I didn't find anywhere how to add a cross to close this message, without page reloading, I wanted to hide it automatically after 2 seconds.

What I did:

```
$("#add-patient").replaceWith("<%= j (render :partial => 'registrants/add_patient') %>");
$("#flash-messages").after("<div class='alert alert-success'> Patient Added </div>").fadeOut(2000);
```

But nothing happens, the message does not disappear nor do I get any error in the console. How to fadeout this message or at least put "x" to close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [delay](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) function after the message has been displayed and before the fadeOut to delay the transition. Also, are you meaning to append the message to the `flash-messages` object? As it is now, you are applying the message  after the `flash-messages` object, yet the fadeOut is being applied to `flash-messages`. Here is a rough example of what you could do.

Note: you could also use append instead of html to add additional content to `flash-messages` if there is some already existing.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#flash-messages").html("<div class='alert alert-success'> Patient Added </div>").fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flash-messages"></div>
```